# Displaying decimal in X/32 or X/16 in same cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

In cell "H27" the decimal total is .95692. I want to take the decimal amount in "H27" and display it as a fraction in "H30".

The total in this example is over 61/64", so I want it to round to the next 64th or  as 15/16".

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1393319/edit) to give us sample data, expected results, what you've tried so far and how it fails to meet expectations?

Comment: nicknicknickandnick's answer [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/37855-fractions-16ths-32nds-64ths.html) may be of interest

Comment: you can use `# ??/??` but it will not always be a power of 2 in the denominator.

Comment: The next 64th is 31/32 not 15/16 which is down not up.